# Given a page ID, how to display entire page (header/content/footer/sidebars) from a plugin hook

Tags: templates, hooks

Given a page ID it it possible to display the page content from within a plugin hook.

I would like to know if it is possible to display the ***entire*** page given a page ID (Header/Footer/Sidebar/Content/etc..)

For example, if the Page ID "123" is the "Home" page then the output from `render_entire_wordpress_page(123);` would be identical to visiting the normal "Home" page. If the Page ID "321" is the "Blog" page then the output from `render_entire_wordpress_page(321)` would be identical to visiting the normal "Blog" page.

Is this possible?

I can somewhat achieve this by filtering `rewrite_rules_array` and then flushing, however I'm trying to output this content after all rewrite rules have finished processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to know if it is possible to display the entire page given a page ID

Yes, `http://site.com/?p=ID` or `http://site.com/index.php?p=ID`. Request that address via AJAX or the [HTTP API](http://codex.wordpress.org/HTTP_API).

WordPress pages render on page load. There is nothing that I know of that "pre-renders" a page that would let you grab the whole generated source without a request to the server for it.

Comment: Thanks, seems to be the only way. Bugger some hosting providers block loopback HTTP connections. I'll give it a go anyway.

Comment: If you are able to use AJAX loopback connections would not be a problem, since the request would come from the client (browser).